# How to make this Flock behaviour work in Java?

Tags: java, path-finding

I'm having trouble implementing Flock Behaviour. What I expect is that the boids should move towards the mouse coordinate but they dont.

Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable, MouseMotionListener{
    private Target mouse;
    private List<Boid> boids;
    int delay = 20;
    private int width = 900, height = 900;
    Thread thread;



    public MainPanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setFocusable(true);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        thread = new Thread(this);
        mouse = new Target(20, 40);;

        boids = new ArrayList<>();


        boids.add(new Boid(320, 30, this));
        boids.add(new Boid(330, 80, this));
        boids.add(new Boid(360, 130, this));
        boids.add(new Boid(420, 20, this));
        boids.add(new Boid(390, 30, this));

        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            mouse.update();

            for (Boid b : boids) {
                b.run();
            }

            repaint();

            try {
                thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        mouse.paint(g2d);

        for (Boid b : boids) {
            b.paint(g2d);
        }

        g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        String s1 = "MX: %8.2f         MY: %8.2f";
        String s2 = "CX: %8.2f         CY: %8.2f";
        g2d.drawString(String.format(s1, mouse.getX(), mouse.getY()), 10, 20);
    }

    public List<Boid> getBoids() {
        return boids;
    }

    public double getTargetX() {
        return mouse.getX();
    }
    public double getTargetY() {
        return mouse.getY();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        mouse.setPos(e.getX(), e.getY());
    }
}


-----------------------------------------------------------

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.List;

public class Boid {
    private double x, y;
    private double accX, accY; // acceleration
    private double vx, vy; // velocity
    private MainPanel panel;
    double maxSpeed = 16;
    //double maxForce = 3;
    double mass = 2;
    double weightingFactor = 5. / 6;
    int r = 40;


    // separation
    double sepX;
    double sepY;

    // alignment
    double aliX;
    double aliY;

    // cohesion
    double cohX;
    double cohY;

    // seek
    double seeX;
    double seeY;

    public Boid(double x, double y, MainPanel panel) {
        // current coordinate
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        // acceleration
        accX = 0;
        accY = 0;

        // velocity
        vx = 3;
        vy = 3;


        sepX = 0;
        sepY = 0;
        aliX = 0;
        aliY = 0;
        cohX = 0;
        cohY = 0;
        seeX = 0;
        seeY = 0;

        this.panel = panel;
    }

    public void run() {
        flock();
        update();
    }

    private void update() {
        // update velocity
        //vx = vx + accX;
        //vy = vy + accY;

        // limit speed
        //vx = Math.min(vx, maxSpeed);
        //vy = Math.min(vy, maxSpeed);

        x = x + vx;
        y = y + vy;

        // reset acceleration to 0 each cycle
        accX = 0;
        accY = 0;
    }

    private void flock() {
        seek();


        List<Boid> boids = panel.getBoids();
        // accumulate a new acceleration each time based on three rules
        separete(boids);
        align(boids);
        cohesion(boids);

        // arbitrarily weight these forces
        sepX = sepX * 1.5;
        sepY = sepY * 1.5;

        aliX = aliX * 1;
        aliY = aliY * 1;

        cohX = cohX * 1;
        cohY = cohY * 1;

        // add the force vectors to acceleration
        // We could add mass here if we want A = F / M

        accX = seeX + sepX + aliX + cohX;
        accY = seeY + sepY + aliY + cohY;
        vx = accX;
        vy = accY;
    }

    // Checks for nearby boids and steers away
    private void separete(List<Boid> boids) {
        double desiredseparation = 25.0f;
        double steeringX = 0;
        double steeringY = 0;
        int count = 0;

        // For every boid in the system, check if it's too close
        double ed = 0;
        double dx = 0;
        double dy = 0;
        for (Boid other : boids) {
            dx = other.getX() - x;
            dy = other.getY() - y;
            ed = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            if (ed > 0 && ed < desiredseparation) {
                // calculate vector pointing away from neighbour
                double diffX = other.getX() - x;
                double diffY = other.getY() - y;

                // normalise
                diffX = diffX / ed;
                diffY = diffY / ed;

                // weight by distance
                diffX = diffX / ed;
                diffY = diffY / ed;

                steeringX = steeringX + diffX;
                steeringY = steeringY + diffY;
                count++; // count how many
            }
        }

        // average -- ??
        if (count > 0) {
            steeringX = steeringX / count;
            steeringY = steeringY / count;
        }

        ed = Math.sqrt(steeringX * steeringX + steeringY * steeringY);
        if (ed > 0) {
            double desiredVX = steeringX / ed * maxSpeed;
            double desiredVY = steeringY / ed * maxSpeed;

            double steeringVX = desiredVX - vx;
            double steeringVY = desiredVY - vy;

            double tvx = ((vx * weightingFactor) + (steeringVX * (1 - weightingFactor) / mass));
            double tvy = ((vy * weightingFactor) + (steeringVY * (1 - weightingFactor) / mass));
            double tve = Math.sqrt(tvx * tvx + tvy * tvy);
            double tvlen = Math.min(tve, maxSpeed);
            vx = tvx / tve * tvlen;
            vy = tvy / tve * tvlen;

            sepX = vx;
            sepY = vy;
        }

        sepX = steeringX;
        sepY = steeringY;
    }

    //Calculate the average velocity for every nearby boid
    private void align(List<Boid> boids) {
        double neighborDistance = 50;
        double sumX = 0;
        double sumY = 0;
        int count = 0;

        double ed = 0;
        double dx = 0;
        double dy = 0;
        for (Boid other : boids) {
            dx = other.getX() - x;
            dy = other.getY() - y;
            ed = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            if (ed > 0 && ed < neighborDistance) {
                sumX = sumX + other.getVX();
                sumY = sumY + other.getVY();
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (count > 0) {
            sumX = sumX / count;
            sumY = sumY / count;
            ed = Math.sqrt(sumX * sumX + sumY * sumY);

            double desiredVX = sumX / ed * maxSpeed;
            double desiredVY = sumY / ed * maxSpeed;

            double steeringVX = desiredVX - vx;
            double steeringVY = desiredVY - vy;

            double tvx = ((vx * weightingFactor) + (steeringVX * (1 - weightingFactor) / mass));
            double tvy = ((vy * weightingFactor) + (steeringVY * (1 - weightingFactor) / mass));
            double tve = Math.sqrt(tvx * tvx + tvy * tvy);
            double tvlen = Math.min(tve, maxSpeed);
            vx = tvx / tve * tvlen;
            vy = tvy / tve * tvlen;

            aliX = vx;
            aliY = vy;
        } else {
            aliX = 0;
            aliY = 0;
        }
    }

    // Calculate steering vector towards that position for the average position (i.e. center) of all nearby boids
    private void cohesion(List<Boid> boids) {
        double neighborDistance = 50;
        double sumX = 0;
        double sumY = 0;
        int count = 0;

        double ed = 0;
        double dx = 0;
        double dy = 0;
        for (Boid other : boids) {
            dx = other.getX() - x;
            dy = other.getY() - y;
            ed = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            if (ed > 0 && ed < neighborDistance) {
                sumX = sumX + other.getVX();
                sumY = sumY + other.getVY();
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (count > 0) {
            sumX = sumX / count;
            sumY = sumY / count;
            seek(sumX, sumY);
        } else {
            cohX = 0;
            cohY = 0;
        }
    }

    private void seek(double tx, double ty) {
        double dx = tx - x;
        double dy = ty - y;
        double ed = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy); // distance to the target
        if (ed > 0) {
            double desiredVX = dx / ed * maxSpeed;
            double desiredVY = dy / ed * maxSpeed;
            // double steeringVX = desiredVX + vx;
            // double steeringVY = desiredVY + vy;
            double steeringVX = desiredVX - vx;
            double steeringVY = desiredVY - vy;

            double v = Math.sqrt(steeringVX * steeringVX + steeringVY * steeringVY);
            if (v != 0.0) {
                // truncate with max speed
                steeringVX = steeringVX / v * Math.min(v, maxSpeed);
                steeringVY = steeringVY / v * Math.min(v, maxSpeed);
            }

            double tvx = ((vx * weightingFactor) + (steeringVX * (1 - weightingFactor) / mass));
            double tvy = ((vy * weightingFactor) + (steeringVY * (1 - weightingFactor) / mass));
            double tve = Math.sqrt(tvx * tvx + tvy * tvy);
            double tvlen = Math.min(tve, maxSpeed);
            vx = tvx / tve * tvlen;
            vy = tvy / tve * tvlen;

            cohX = vx;
            cohY = vy;
        }
    }

    private void seek() {
        double dx = panel.getTargetX() - x;
        double dy = panel.getTargetY() - y;
        double ed = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy); // distance to the target
        if (ed > 0) {
            double desiredVX = dx / ed * maxSpeed;
            double desiredVY = dy / ed * maxSpeed;
            // double steeringVX = desiredVX + vx;
            // double steeringVY = desiredVY + vy;
            double steeringVX = desiredVX - seeX;
            double steeringVY = desiredVY - seeY;

            double v = Math.sqrt(steeringVX * steeringVX + steeringVY * steeringVY);
            if (v != 0.0) {
                // truncate with max speed
                steeringVX = steeringVX / v * Math.min(v, maxSpeed);
                steeringVY = steeringVY / v * Math.min(v, maxSpeed);
            }

            double tvx = ((seeX * weightingFactor) + (steeringVX * (1 - weightingFactor) / mass));
            double tvy = ((seeY * weightingFactor) + (steeringVY * (1 - weightingFactor) / mass));
            double tve = Math.sqrt(tvx * tvx + tvy * tvy);
            double tvlen = Math.min(tve, maxSpeed);
            seeX = tvx / tve * tvlen;
            seeY = tvy / tve * tvlen;
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillRect((int) (x + .5), (int) (y + .5), 20, 20);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawOval((int)x - r / 2, (int)y - r / 2, r, r);
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    // Get velocity 
    public double getVX() {
        return vx;
    }

    public double getVY() {
        return vy;
    }
}


-----------------------------------------------------------

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Target {
    private int x, y, vx, vy, r;

    public Target(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        r = 100;
    }

    public void setPos(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void update() {
    }

    public void stop() {
        vx = 0;
        vy = 0;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawOval(x - r / 2, y - r / 2, r, r);
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }
}

-----------------------------------------------------------

import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    public Test() {
        Container container = getContentPane();
        container.add(new MainPanel());
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test gameFrame = new Test();
        gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gameFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `mouse` is used solely inside `MainPanel`, but the flock behavior is calculated inside `Boid` which does not make use of `MainPanel.mouse`. Thus the mouse coordinates have no influence on the swarm behavior in your code.

Comment: I see from a deleted answer that you seem to have created a duplicate account. You can [follow the instructions here to merge your accounts](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to post comments on this page and edit your question if you need to, as well as mark an answer as accepted.

Comment: @DMGregory, I merged the accounts. Thanks for the instructions.

Comment: @Thomas, Thanks for pointing out. I fixed the code to use mouse coordinate.

Comment: You could checkout https://github.com/ClickerMonkey/Steerio to see how steering behaviors are implemented in Java.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that the boids do not know where the mouse is. I searched your source for calls to `getTargetX` or `getTargetY` and didn't find any.

The standard boids algorithm doesn't use a target. I believe you can modify your implementation to include one by adding another influence in `Boids.run` that draws the boid toward the mouse position.

Something along these lines would make sense to me:

Add a function to find the target position. This can start out as a copy of `seek`. Instead of taking in parameters `tx` and `ty` it will read them from the panel, and instead of saving results to `cohX` and `cohY` it will save them to two new members.

Call this new function from `flock`, and then add the values of new members to `accX` and `accY`.

Comment: T,I implemented the instructions but still need some adjustments because the boids do not smoothly flock.